# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException when using Axiom to send a SOAP

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis, soap-client, axiom

I have the following code

```
    final String METHOD="test";
    final String PARAM1_VAL="Hello";
    final String TARGET_EPR="http://bhanuka-TECRA-M11:8280/services/SoapToRestProxy";

    SOAPFactory factory = OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP11Factory();
    OMNamespace samplesNamespace = factory.createOMNamespace("http://services.samples/xsd", "m");
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = factory.getDefaultEnvelope();


    OMElement requestElement = factory.createOMElement("request", samplesNamespace);
    OMElement methodElement = factory.createOMElement("method",samplesNamespace);
    OMElement param1 = factory.createOMElement("val",samplesNamespace);

    param1.setText(PARAM1_VAL);
    methodElement.setText(METHOD);
    requestElement.addChild(methodElement);
    requestElement.addChild(param1);
    envelope.getBody().addChild(requestElement);

    try {
        ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
        Options options = new Options();
        options.setTo(new EndpointReference(TARGET_EPR));
        serviceClient.setOptions(options);

        OMElement response = serviceClient.sendReceive(envelope);
        System.out.println(response);
    } catch (AxisFault axisFault) {
        axisFault.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What I am doing is making a SOAP envelope and sending it to a specific Endpoint. but in the `sendReceive` method, it throws an

> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Can not output XML declaration,
>   after other output has already been done.

What I am doing Wrong here ? somebody please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServiceClient#sendReceive(OMElement)` doesn't expect a `SOAPEnvelope` as input, but the content of the SOAP body. Instead of passing it `envelope`, you should pass it `requestElement`.

Comment: can you tell me how to get the `requestElement` from the evelope :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You have a variable named `requestElement` in your code. Just pass that to `sendReceive`.